# Why can't I install Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I was trying to install Ubuntu on my pc, and I have enough space on my computer, but why can't I click on the *Install now* button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using gparted in a live session and resizing the xp partition, then start the install, but instead of selecting "install alongside" select "something else" and create a new partition in the space that you created by selecting it, pressing "change" in the lower left corner, choosing the first dropdown, selecting "ext4", then "format" then in the next dropdown, "/", then try continuing with the installation.